# Type equivalence in $\lambda\underline\omega$ under lambda abstraction

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I'm going through "Type Theory and Formal Proof" by Nederpelt and Geuvers and just trying to play around with $\lambda\underline\omega$ after reading the chapter on it to better grasp the material. The text is a bit vague on some formalities, so I have a couple of questions.

Consider the term $t = \lambda x : ((\lambda \alpha : *. \alpha) nat). x$ (assuming $nat : *$ is in context). Can type-level abstractions and applications be used like this under lambda abstraction type annotations? So, is $t$ a valid term?

If it is, then clearly its type is $(\lambda \alpha : *. \alpha) nat \rightarrow (\lambda \alpha : *. \alpha) nat$, which is $\beta$-equivalent to $nat \rightarrow nat$. But how does $t$ relate to $\lambda x:nat.x$? In other words, can $\beta$-reduction be done under the lambda abstraction type annotation?

Comment: What do $nat$ and $*$ denote here?

Comment: $nat$ is some type of the kind $*$, and $*$ is, well, the kind of usual types (the ones you'd also encounter in STLC).

Comment: Ah, so you want a 'varying type' or some, i.e. a lambda expression for the type part (after the colon). I think it has another formalism on that part (maybe '*dependent types*') and lambda expressions are only for terms.. But I'm not a lambda calculus expert..

Comment: Yep, that's types dependent on types (basically STLC lifted to the type level).